# Excel 2013. Address from Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, calendar

I have two spreadsheets, one with a Calendar, and the other one with Data Chart.
I'm trying to make it so that the Data Chart will only start using Data from Today's date in the Calendar. (Note: Calendar has other things, like % work done, hours spent, etc).
For that I'm trying to use the:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A100);A1:A100;0);1;1;1;"")
```

and infact I do get the address '!$A$88', but I cannot use this address because it has an exclamation  mark in front of it. How do I use this address? Is there a way to remove this exclamation mark and start using this cell address in another formula, in a different spreadsheet?

PS.
I will be using MATCH(TODAY()), not MAX()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotation marks are using the *sheet_text* [attribute](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/address-HP005208983.aspx). Remove them like this:

```
 =ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A100);A1:A100;0);1;1;1)
```

You'll get your reference.

Or use the actual sheet like this:

```
 =ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A100);A1:A100;0);1;1;1;"Sheet1")
```

Using `today()` it looks like

```
 =(ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(),A1:A100,0);1;1;1))
```

or

```
 =(ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(),A1:A100,0);1;1;1;"Sheet1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I still cannot use the address of !Sheet1!$A$88, it refers to it as text "!Sheet1!$A$88"

Comment: @AlekseiDmitrijev that isn't happening to me.. try it wrapped in an `=indirect`. We have regional differences but my formula that works is `=(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A100),A1:A100,0),1,1,1))`